# okhttp sometimes request have no response

Tags: android, okhttp

i have use okhttp3 to request network.sometimes when i put a net request and l have set

```
mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build();
```

CONNECTION_TIME_OUT is 10.but 15s later i can not get a response. if i still wait, the request still no response.it most like the request is holing up.
because when i close my wifi the requst can be response and the result is timeout exception. whate is wrong whit me?
and i write the response into the sdcard. is this cause?

```
private void deliveryResult(ResultCallback callback, final Request request) {
    if (callback == null) callback = DEFAULT_RESULT_CALLBACK;
    final ResultCallback resCallBack = callback;
    deliveryResultCore(request, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            LogUtil.i(request.tag().toString(), "request fail " + e);
            sendFailedStringCallback(request, e, resCallBack);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                MyResponse mrs = new MyResponse();
                mrs.code = response.code();
                mrs.content = response.body().string();
                mrs.isSuccessful = response.isSuccessful();
                mrs.accessToken = response.header("x-access-token");

                LogUtil.i(request.tag().toString(), "request success ", mrs); // this will be wtite the log into sdcard
                sendSuccessResultCallback(mrs, resCallBack);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sendFailedStringCallback(response.request(), e, resCallBack);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

later l got W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.234ms . is this cause?

Answer (score 0):

Your CONNECTION_TIME_OUT variable might be too low. You have to increase the amount of time before the time out occurs like [e.g: 60 seconds].

A reason for the time out is possibly because the server is taking too long to reply or the internet is slow.

Comment: thanks. but i think the okhttpClinet must give out response when 10s later.beacuse i have set timeout Time. i don't know whate cause this.this request same to be holding up if i turn off my NetEnvironment the okhttpClinet can have a response right now but if i do nothing the requset will never return a response.